# como solucionar sql error 104 token unknown en firebird 2.5

Tags: sql, firebird

Buen dia, estoy tratando de ejecutar un script ,en firebird 2.5, que contiene el siguiente código:

```
CREATE OR ALTER procedure INSERTARASIENTOAFECHA (
    FECHA date, CODIGOEJERCICIO integer)
returns (
    NUMEROASIENTO double precision)
as
declare variable V_AUXILIAR double precision;
begin
  select max(numeroasiento)
  from cabezaasientos
  where codigoejercicio=:codigoejercicio 
    and fecha <= :fecha into numeroasiento;

  numeroasiento= numeroasiento + 1;

  select codigoasiento
  from cabezaasientos
  where codigoejercicio= :codigoejercicio 
    and numeroasiento= :numeroasiento into :v_auxiliar;

  if (v_auxiliar is not null) then
  begin
    update cabezaasientos
    set numeroasiento= numeroasiento + 1
    where codigoejercicio= :codigoejercicio 
      and numeroasiento > (:numeroasiento-1)
    order by codigoejercicio,numeroasiento DESC;

    update parametros
    set valor = valor + 1
    where tipodocumento='AS';
  end

  suspend;

end;

commit work; ← arroja error aca



execute block as
  declare variable codigo doble;
  declare variable numero doble;

begin
  /* generacion de asientos*/
    SELECT P.VALOR
    FROM PARAMETROS P
    WHERE P.tipodocumento ='CA' INTO :codigo;
    
    UPDATE PARAMETROS P
    SET P.VALOR= P.VALOR+1
    WHERE P.tipodocumento ='CA';

    SELECT NumeroAsiento
    FROM insertarasientoafecha('01/14/2021',4) into :numero;

  execute statement 'UPDATE PARAMETROS SET VALOR = valor + 1 where tipodocumento = ''CA''';

Insert Into CabezaAsientos Values (codigo,4,numero,'ANULACION / PA 00000-00002198/ - ','01/14/2021',9,'01/14/2021',0);

Insert Into CuerpoAsientos  Values (codigo,1,11102003,56961.54,1, '01/14/2021',0) ;

Insert Into CuerpoAsientos  Values (codigo,2,11102002,1995.15,1,'01/14/2021',0);

Insert Into CuerpoAsientos  Values (codigo,3,21203020,1496.36,1,'01/14/2021',0) ;

Insert Into CuerpoAsientos  Values (codigo,4,21101001,60453.05,0,'01/14/2021',0) ;

Insert Into ComprobantesAsientos Values (codigo,'FA',300081148,'E','01278','01/12/2021',0) ;

Insert Into ComprobantesAsientos Values (codigo,'AGIP-R-15',100000212,'E','01278','01/14/2021',0)  ;

Insert Into ComprobantesAsientos Values (codigo,'ARBA-R-23',100000213,'E','01278','01/14/2021',0)   ;

end

commit work;



drop procedure INSERTARASIENTOAFECHA ;
```

Cuando lo quiero correr en la base de datos me arroja error en la linea donde esta el `commit work`, el error es SQL error code = -104. Token unknown - line 39, column 1. commit.

Si quito el commit work el error se traslada a la linea de abajo. La verdad he intentando varios cambios pero me sigue saltando el error y la verdad no se que es.

Comment: ese `END;` al final del procedimiento, lleva punto y coma? La [documentación](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd21-ddl-procedure.html) dice que no

Comment: Si lo quito igual sigue tirando el error en el commit work, ni idea por que

Comment: Es que no sé de firebird pero no encuentro ese COMMIT WORK en la documentación. No será que no es necesario porque las sentencias DDL no lo requieren? (uno hace commit de cambios en los datos, no de cambios en la estructura porque se aplican de inmediato)

Comment: Yo estoy igual, ese COMMIT WORK lo utilizo porque así me lo requieren, yo solo hice la lógica del procedimiento y para correrlo me indican que tengo que utilizar ese COMMIT WORK.

Comment: Hm, yo sugiero contradecirles y hacer la prueba sin ese comando ahí. Si el procedimiento queda, entonces están equivocados. Otros como [flyway](https://flywaydb.org/documentation/database/firebird) ejecutan los scripts sin esa sentencia... la [documentación oficial](https://www.ib-aid.com/en/transactions-in-firebird-acid-isolation-levels-deadlocks-and-update-conflicts-resolution/) usa COMMIT sólo para INSERT y otras operaciones DML